# Это СПП или нет? Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

Решил запятые вспомнить.
"Я пошел домой когда стемнело".
Перед "когда" нужна запятая, это СПП или что это?

Answer (score 2):

Да, это сложноподчинённое предложение (СПП), запятая нужна.

***Я пошел домой, когда стемнело.***

Запятая разделяет два простых предложения в составе сложного. Подчинительный временной союз ***когда*** связывает главное предложение (основа – ***Я пошел***) с придаточным безличным (сказуемое – ***стемнело***).